# Flutter how to rerun future?

Tags: dart, flutter, future

Is it possible to make future somehow like a re-runnable task? For example, if I have to made a network call using a future and it failed for authentication reason. I would like to re-run the network call future once auth succeeded. How can I do that?

My expected code would probably look similar to this

```
Future task = fetchData();

Future handleService(task) async {
  try {
    final data = await task;
    return data;
  } catch (ex) {
    // requires authentication
    if(ex.code == 202) {
      bool authSuccess = await reAuth();
      if (authSuccess) {
        await task
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple answer: you can't re-run a Future.

Future can be completed only once. Moreover, Future represents the *result* of an async computation. I think about it that way: you run a *task* that returns a token (Future). When the tasks comletes, it sets the value on the Future.

On top of that, Future can have its value set only once, it cannot be completed with 2 different values (even by the task whose result it represents) Once a value is set, it will always hold the same one, and not allow modification.

In your case, you need to call `fetchData` again.

If you have a function that may return multiple values, you can use a `Stream`, but this approach doesn't fit your problem.

Comment: Is there an alternative? Simply just recalling fetchData introduce a lot of boilerplate code which is something that Im trying to avoid.

Comment: You can encapsulate re-fetch logic just like in your example. Instead of passing in a Future (result of a function call) pass in the function to be called (functions can be passed in as arguments)